# How to create a Report Library?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

Any ideas how to create a report library with c# for Sp2010?

I Used always SPListTemplateType.*mystuff but there is no option for Report Library

```
site.Lists.Add("MyLibrary", "MyLibrary", SPListTemplateType.?);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype%28v=office.12%29.aspx its not there as option. What should I do? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [SPListCollection.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms448694.aspx) override that includes Feature ID and Template Type:

```
site.Lists.Add("MyLibrary", 
    "MyLibrary", 
    "MyLibrary", 
    "{2510d73f-7109-4ccc-8a1c-314894deeb3a}", 
    433, 
    "101");
```

Answer (score 2):

The Lists.Add method has overrides that allow you to specify the template id as and integer or the template name as a string.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms425818.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One of SPList.Add() overloads takes an SPListTemplate (not SPListTemplateType enum that you use)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms477358.aspx

First fetch SPListTemplate, then use it to add the list:

```
SPListTemplate reportTemplate = site.ListTemplates["Report Library"]; // note displayname, so might be different depending on language
Guid listGuid = site.Lists.Add("MyLibrary","MyDescription",reportTemplate);
```